# No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'android.support.design'

Tags: android

I created a library project from

```
android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\design\design-25.0.1.aar
```

I added `appcompat`, `recyclerview` and `cardview` libraries.

There is an error message:

> design_25.0.1\res\color\design_tint_password_toggle.xml:19: error: 
>   No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'android.support.design'

This is the code of `design_tint_password_toggle.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="?android:attr/colorForeground" app:alpha="0.54"/>
    <item android:color="?android:attr/colorForeground" app:alpha="0.38"/>
</selector>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: how did you fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Its work for me.

Change here:-

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

to

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib-auto">

Comment: that file is part of the support library, you can't change it

Answer (score 0):

I found doing a clean build first fixed this issue for me. (I was trying to upgrade from 23.0.1 -> 24.2.1)